# OSCommerce: HOW to get the Value in Shipping Cost?

Tags: oscommerce

OSCommerce:

In order total, I just need the variable of the shipping cost. I need condition like, if shipping cost is zero then..... else ....

Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to get the selected shipping method cost during checkout.  The first way is to grab the cost from the $order object, like this:

```
if ($order->info['shipping_cost'] <= 0) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

If you need to get the shipping cost without the use of the $order object, you can use the $shipping $_SESSION variable.  You can easily check the selected shipping method cost like this:

```
if ($shipping['cost'] <= 0) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but I've just found a solution before you made reply. Once again thank you very much even if the answer is late. Cheers to you my friend.